# html - <video> tag doesn't work in google chrome

Tags: html

I was wondering why this code
`<video src="http://brexes.com/Images%20and%20Videos/GamilaSecretVideo.mp4" controls></video>`
works on every browser instead google chrome?!
Is there any way to get it work on all the browser containing google chrome?
Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/TQ4d4/
Just try to open it in google chrome and different browsers.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome.

Comment: Same code I gave you? Are you sure?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Oh it worked for me now, I just had to close the browser and re-open it